# Pushes open tracking with Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have implemented the push open tracking like described here https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications-tracking-pushes-and-app-opens.

If i open the push on the device, in the parse dashboard, the push opens number is updated on the previous push sent.
For example, if i send the push "Hello" twice and open it twice on the device, the push opens will be 1 for the first push, 0 for the last one.
I can reproduce it if the app is in background or if it's closed.

I use the latest pod Parse (1.11.0) and the application is in Swift.

The source code :

```
    func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
      if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
      }
    }
```

I tried with the following code to check if the BFTask is completed. Everything is fine and the task has the completed status.

```
PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in

                assert(task.completed, "task should have completed")

                assert(!task.cancelled, "task should not have been cancelled")

                assert(!task.faulted, "task should not complete due to error or exception")

                return task
})
```

Did someone experience the same issue ?